# Increasing security against PHP shells

Tags: php

I have disabled a bunch of functions in PHP like passthru, shell_exec, etc, but that isn't good enough. I downloaded a few shells (r57 and c99 specifically), and am going through them. What I see is a lot of calls to files in /etc/ and /var/. is there any way to prevent these files from being read by the nginx user? The user nginx is running as is 'nobody'.

I was considering writing a module for nginx or a php extension, but not if there is an easier way that doesn't require me to fail at writing good C.

I also notice a lot of these shells use the mysql_* functions, and none of my applications use or will ever use that. is there a setting in the ini file that i can use to disable those functions?

I also wanted to note that I KNOW that security from shells should be in place BEFORE they can even upload one to begin with, but i want to take extra precautions. serverfault is dead so i posted here.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx, but can't you security-sandbox each website? That said, I can't see any harm in allowing read access to /etc/ and /var/. I'm not sure what kind of vulnerability you think exists.

Comment: Just looking at this one shell, they can fopen/fread /etc/passwd and other cpanel configuration files etc

Comment: You're trying to prevent PHP from doing things after the server's been compromised.  Just make sure that you restrict where the server process can write & ensure that nothing in there is executable is a far better use of time than trying to blacklist every potentially harmful function is closing the barn door after all the horses are gone.

Comment: For the mysql_* functions, can you just compile a build of PHP without them?